# How to avoid irresponsible app by rendering time consuming component later on

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that takes some time to be loaded (1-2 seconds), and when I switch between tabs, it takes a lot of time for the tab to be seen because it waits for that time consuming component to be fully loaded.

Here's an example:

```
function App() {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setTab(1)}>tab 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setTab(2)}>tab 2</button>

      {tab === 1 && <div>Hello World</div>}
      {tab === 2 && (
      <div>
        <FastRenderComponent />
        <FastRenderComponent />
        <SlowRenderComponent />
      </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to render the SlowRenderComponent only after the other components have been rendered so it won't take 1-2 seconds to be able to switch between tabs, but that it would be seamlessly.

How can I achieve that?

**Note:** I tried to wrap SlowRenderComponent with Suspense but it only worked once. An example to SlowRenderComponent:

```
export default function SlowRenderComponent() {
  let calculation = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 2 * 1e8; i++) {
    calculation += i + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
  }
  return <div>Slow Component, Calculation={calculation}</div>;
}
```

Comment: You could implement Lazy load on your slow component. Additionally, you could use a custom hook based on intersection observer API, that way you could achieve the effect of the component loading only when it's visible in the viewport.

Comment: Depends what takes time and how you want to deal with it. The most straight forward solution is to add some loading state to your slow component, so it can avoid blocking and render it's content once it's finished.

Comment: @super How would I know if it has finished to load? I guess as ivanatias said I could use React.lazy

Comment: That's correct. Lazy load + `Suspense` should work, and if you need it you could add the custom hook implementation I commented. I can elaborate more on this last part in an answer if you want.

Comment: Since @ivanatias was first I'd accept his answer first, but if he won't respond go ahead and do so :-)

Comment: @Dorki You just update the loading state once it has finished.